# emacs org bullets not working

Tags: org-mode, terminal-emacs, ubuntu

I'm using emacs on ubuntu 19.04. This is my init file

```
(use-package org
    :ensure t
    :pin org)

(use-package org-bullets
      :ensure t
      :config
      (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-bullets-mode 1))))
```

bullets are not supported in the terminal mode as well as GUI mode

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

I tried `M-x RET revert-buffer-with-coding-system` and tried different UTF encodings available such as `utf-8`, `utf-8-unix`, `utf-8-dos`, `utf-8-mac`, `prefer-utf-8`, `prefer-utf-8-unix` and so on.. but no sulution

`M-x RET describe-current-coding` output

```
Coding system for saving this buffer:
  U -- utf-8-dos (alias: mule-utf-8-dos cp65001-dos)

Default coding system (for new files):
  U -- utf-8 (alias: mule-utf-8 cp65001)

Coding system for keyboard input:
  U -- utf-8-unix (alias: mule-utf-8-unix cp65001-unix)

Coding system for terminal output:
  U -- utf-8 (alias: mule-utf-8 cp65001)

Coding system for inter-client cut and paste:
  nil
Defaults for subprocess I/O:
  decoding: U -- utf-8-unix (alias: mule-utf-8-unix cp65001-unix)

  encoding: U -- utf-8-unix (alias: mule-utf-8-unix cp65001-unix)


Priority order for recognizing coding systems when reading files:
  1. utf-8 (alias: mule-utf-8 cp65001)
  2. iso-2022-7bit 
  3. iso-latin-1 (alias: iso-8859-1 latin-1)
  4. iso-2022-7bit-lock (alias: iso-2022-int-1)
  5. iso-2022-8bit-ss2 
  6. emacs-mule 
  7. raw-text 
  8. iso-2022-jp (alias: junet)
  9. in-is13194-devanagari (alias: devanagari)
  10. chinese-iso-8bit (alias: cn-gb-2312 euc-china euc-cn cn-gb gb2312)
  11. utf-8-auto 
  12. utf-8-with-signature 
  13. utf-16 
  14. utf-16be-with-signature (alias: utf-16-be)
  15. utf-16le-with-signature (alias: utf-16-le)
  16. utf-16be 
  17. utf-16le 
  18. japanese-shift-jis (alias: shift_jis sjis)
  19. chinese-big5 (alias: big5 cn-big5 cp950)
  20. undecided 

  Other coding systems cannot be distinguished automatically
  from these, and therefore cannot be recognized automatically
  with the present coding system priorities.

Particular coding systems specified for certain file names:

  OPERATION TARGET PATTERN      CODING SYSTEM(s)
  --------- --------------      ----------------
  File I/O      "\\.tzst\\'"            (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.zst\\'"             (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.dz\\'"              (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.txz\\'"             (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.xz\\'"              (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.lzma\\'"            (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.lz\\'"              (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.g?z\\'"             (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.\\(?:tgz\\|svgz\\|sifz\\)\\'"
                                        (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.tbz2?\\'"           (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.bz2\\'"             (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.Z\\'"               (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.elc\\'"             utf-8-emacs
                "\\.el\\'"              prefer-utf-8
                "\\.utf\\(-8\\)?\\'"    utf-8
                "\\.xml\\'"             xml-find-file-coding-system
                "\\(\\`\\|/\\)loaddefs.el\\'"
                                        (raw-text . raw-text-unix)
                "\\.tar\\'"             (no-conversion . no-conversion)
                "\\.po[tx]?\\'\\|\\.po\\."
                                        po-find-file-coding-system
                "\\.\\(tex\\|ltx\\|dtx\\|drv\\)\\'"
                                        latexenc-find-file-coding-system
                ""                      (undecided)
  Process I/O   nothing specified
  Network I/O   nothing specified
```

Comment: In all such cases it's best to start by reporting (1) $ locale **and** (2) $ locale -a (both from shell ie outside emacs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding the following into my init file solved the issue

```lisp
  (set-language-environment 'utf-8)                                                           
  (setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)                                                          

  ;; set the default encoding system                                                          
  (prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)                                                               
  (setq default-file-name-coding-system 'utf-8)                                               
  (set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)                                                         
  (set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)                                                         
  (set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)                                                         

  ;; Treat clipboard input as UTF-8 string first; compound text next, etc.                    
  (setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING))
```

Comment: If this resolved your problem, please accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your terminal font supports UTF, or whatever you've decided to use for your bullet. This works for me in terminal with Inconsolata. You might want to check out [nerd fonts](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts) in case you're having trouble finding something that will properly display

```lisp
(use-package org-bullets
  :hook (org-mode . org-bullets-mode)
  :config
  (setq org-bullets-bullet-list '("◉" "⁑" "⁂" "❖" "✮" "✱" "✸")))
```

Comment: I'm using KDE desktop environment and konsole terminal, how do I check if I have utf support?

Comment: my locale uses uft-8, I made sure of that by checking out other posts. Bullets are not working even in GUI mode. Can't find out what's the issue